# Convert text file into xml

Tags: php, xml, text

I am new to php, therefore I have got a beginner question. I did a text file with some simple data in it and I would like to save that data into a xml file.

I have tried it with a foreach loop, but I struggle at this point. I know what the problem is, but I am to stupid to fix ist.

Here is my text file:

```
Lea
mueller
lea_mueller@web.de
10.03.1984
green
Malte
cool
äödksf@kdölf.com
23.12.54
red
Peter
Pam
ödlfs@we.de
23.23.2323
pink
```

My php:

```
<?php

$file = file("daten.txt");

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$data = $dom->createElement('data');
$dom->appendChild($data);

foreach($file as $value){

    $user = $dom->createElement("user");
    $data->appendChild($user);

        $vorname = $dom->createElement("vorname", "$value");
        $user->appendChild($vorname);

        $nachname = $dom->createElement("nachname", "$value");
        $user->appendChild($nachname);

        $email = $dom->createElement("email", "$value");
        $user->appendChild($email);

        $bday = $dom->createElement("bday", "$value");
        $user->appendChild($bday);

        $color = $dom->createElement("color", "$value");
        $user->appendChild($color);

        }

$dom->save("new.xml");

print_r($file);
?>
```

I always get the name, lastname, email, bday and color four times. I know why, but I dont know, how I can do it in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code you got there, it appears to me that you used $value multiple times hoping it changes to the next line, I think it wouldn't

Try replacing your foreach loop with this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x<count($file); $x+=5){

    $user = $dom->createElement("user");
    $data->appendChild($user);

        $vorname = $dom->createElement("vorname", trim($file[$x]));
        $user->appendChild($vorname);

        $nachname = $dom->createElement("nachname", trim($file[$x+1]));
        $user->appendChild($nachname);

        $email = $dom->createElement("email", trim($file[$x+2]));
        $user->appendChild($email);

        $bday = $dom->createElement("bday", trim($file[$x+3]));
        $user->appendChild($bday);

        $color = $dom->createElement("color", trim($file[$x+4]));
        $user->appendChild($color);

        }
```

Also, please fix your indentations.

Let me know if this works.

Edit: Fixed semicolon usage in loop condition.

Comment: trim the value to remove the `&#13;`

Comment: @albertdiones try to use `for ($x = 0, $c=count($file); $x<$c; $x+=5){` it is more efficient to count only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Was thinking about to do it with a for loop, but had no clue. ty :D

Comment: @bansi I know it's less efficient, but was focusing on making it work; But I didn't know that you can do that inside the for(), thanks for that.

Comment: http://php.net/file has a parameter/flag to remove the line-breaks at the end. check the manual, it's made for exactly cases like the one here. And there is also http://php.net/array_chunk